# Running CefSharp in Powershell

Tags: powershell, cefsharp

I need to show a CefSharp (WPF or Winforms) Webbrowser Control running from a Powershell Script. I extracted the x84 dll's from the nuget package and am trying to add them like this:

```
try{
    Add-Type -Path $PSScriptRoot/CefSharp.Core.dll
    Add-Type -Path $PSScriptRoot/CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.dll
    Add-Type -Path $PSScriptRoot/CefSharp.dll
    Add-Type -Path $PSScriptRoot/CefSharp.WinForms.dll
}
catch{

$_.Exception.Message
}
```

I get the error Message:

> Can not load file ... or dependecy. Module
>   not found.

Is there a way to use CefSharp trough Powershell?

Comment: Are you attempting to load an x86 dll in a 64bit process?  Did you search for the error you are getting before posting here?

Comment: I am using the correct bit version

Comment: Please include the entire error message,  which call is failing?  Have you confirmed the file path you are specifying is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error than you.

I solve the issue, by adding CEF redist package in the same folder than CefSharp dll:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/cef.redist.x64/

https://www.nuget.org/packages/cef.redist.x86/

Official information about CEF:
https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/master/

I publish my sample code for others:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("$AssPath\CefSharp.Core.dll")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("$AssPath\CefSharp.WinForms.dll")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("$AssPath\CefSharp.dll")

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# WinForm Setup
$mainForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$mainForm.Font = "Comic Sans MS,9"
$mainForm.ForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::White
$mainForm.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::DarkSlateBlue
$mainForm.Text = "CefSharp"
$mainForm.Width = 960
$mainForm.Height = 700

[CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser] $browser = New-Object CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser "www.google.com"
$mainForm.Controls.Add($browser)

[void] $mainForm.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 1):

`[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile` does not work with the current CefSharp DDL's and PS7.

Here is the working variant:

```
Import-Module -Name "$AssPath\CefSharp.Core.dll"
Import-Module -Name "$AssPath\CefSharp.WinForms.dll"
Import-Module -Name "$AssPath\CefSharp.dll"
```